# setState not a function after binding this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple form allowing users to create a plain text post. The code below generates a successful server side response following the `createPostRequest` call. However, following a successful post, I would like to update the state to empty out the postBody field and update the UI to reflect this change, and then allow users to make subsequent requests to post additional messages.

Currently, everything works well for the first request only, and after a successful initial request, the postBody field isn't emptying out and when attempting to change the value of the post field following the first initial request, every key stroke is resulting in the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

Note, what is a bit odd, is that I am getting the above error despite binding `this` to the onChange method in the constructor.

Did anyone run into this issue? I appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            postBody : "",
            location: "main"
        };

        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        });
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.props.createPostRequest(this.state).then(
            () => {

                this.setState = ({
                    postBody : ""
                });
            }
        )
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="create-post-inner col-md-12">
                <form id="createPost" onSubmit={ this.onSubmit } >
                    <textarea value={this.state.postBody} className="form-control postInput" name="postBody" onChange={ this.onChange } >
                    </textarea>
                    <span>The value of the state is {this.state.postBody}</span>
                    <input type="submit" className="submit btn btn-primary" />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Why you are so inconsistent? Don't mix arrow functions and binding.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend check this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/h1ofh8w8/) it's working properly, i didn't change anything in this except the prop method calling.

Comment: You are reassigning setState to an object after `createPostRequest`  `this.setState = ({` should be `this.setState({`

Comment: @MayankShukla, I appreciate the reply, however, this does not help as the props call is necessary and as mentioned in the post, successful during the first execution, but resulting in errors after subsequent executions...

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, not sure I understand your suggestion, can you elaborate?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend My suggestion was **NOT** to reassign setState but to call it.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, got it! you were right, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is an extra `=` after this.setState . Change the following to

```
 this.props.createPostRequest(this.state).then(
        () => {

            this.setState({
                postBody : ""
            });
        }
    )
```